Discrepancy in passing array to function
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void myFunction(int myNumbers[5]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout << myNumbers[i] << "\n";
  }
}

int main() {
  int myNumbers[5] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
  myFunction(myNumbers);
  return 0;
}

The type of argument that is expected in myFunction is int [5], while the type that is being provided is int*, but the code is working fine! Can someone please explain why?

Why do you think: while the type that is being provided is int*? I do not see such thing in your code. I think you are confused by fact that array is able to decay into a pointer.

frankly its odd that your question is based on the answer. What i mean is that myNumbers is not an int*, its an array. It does decay to int* when passed to a function. myFunction(int myNumbers[5]) is just a different way to write myFunction(int*). What you pass is a pointer to int because of array to pointer decay. And becaus of array to pointer decay the language lets you write int myNumbers[5] when its actually a int* myNumbers

As a function argument, the type of int myNumbers[5] is int*. That way, C-style arrays are passed as pointers and not by value. And, yes, at the point of call, the name myNumbers decays into a pointer to the first element. Pointers everywhere, despite the array syntax everywhere.

This is one of C quirks. Since C++11 you can use std::array<int, 5> .

And, because of the decays, you could create an array of any size and pass it to myFunction. The 5 doesn't mean anything in the argument type.

You might want void myFunction(const int (&myNumbers)[5]).

You might want to use void myFunction(const std::array<int,5>& myNumbers). See std::array. Since that makes arrays behave exactly the same as any other C++ object, you can even return it from functions like any other object.

This: void myFunction(int myNumbers[5]) is exactly the same as this: void myFunction(int* myNumbers).  The [5] is purely syntactic sugar and means nothing.  It does help in documenting the function to people reading it to suggest that an array of 5 values is being "passed" (when actually, it isn't), but that's it.

This question is similar to: Passing Arrays to Function in C++. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Also What is array to pointer decay


while the type that is being provided is int*

No. The type of myNumbers is int[5], array of 5 integers, it is not int*.
Yes. That array decays to a int*, a pointer to its first element.
Because it is not possible to pass arrays by value, and because arrays do decay to pointers, the language lets you write void myFunction(int myNumbers[5]) when it actually means void myFunction(int* myNumber).
You should read about array to pointer decay. And you should not confuse arrays with pointers. An array is not a pointer and a pointer is not an array. And array to pointer decay does not change that.
TL;DR its a weird oddity inherited from C. Raw arrays are weird.

imagine a world where C had arrays not decay to pointers. stack size would go brrrrrr

@Raildex one could still manually do myFunction(&myNumbers[0]), its the fact that this happens implicitly that commonly causes confusion. Implicit conversions brrrr ;)

Raw arrays decay to pointers because, at the assembly level, there are no arrays. There is only a pointer. It's not a C -> C++, it is a reality -> C++.

@MichaelChourdakis well it could have been how c++ does it wiht std::array. copy by value. although VLA would then probably break.

@MichaelChourdakis sorry, I dont buy this argument. std::string and std::array and std::vector are "just pointers". There is no std::string nor std::array nor std::vector on the assembly level, yet to use those containers we do not need to care about complicated concepts like array to pointer decay. Also same comment as before, the confusion stems from the fact that the decay is implicit. If it was explicit we didnt have the question OP is asking here.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai there is nothing to 'buy'.  Arrays decay to pointers because if they didn't then there wouldn't be any other way to access them. All C++ stuff related to string, array, vector or whatever container eventually end up into a raw pointer.  Yes it's hidden from the programmer but here my comment focused on the fact that you assumed that it 's a C inheritance.

@MichaelChourdakis array to pointer decay and int myNumbers[5] being a different way to write int* is inherited from C.
